# What is the "simple" hashing algorithm that CouchDB uses to encrypt passwords?

Tags: firebase-authentication, couchdb, sha, password-hash

(TL;DR: I have two questions at the bottom.)

I have been looking through CouchDB's documentation to learn about its hashing algorithm, but I'm unable to find important details. 
The most information I've gathered has been from this page: [1.5.2. Authentication Database](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/intro/security.html#users-documents)

Here's my problem: 
I have a bunch of users in a `_users` database in my CouchDB instance on Cloudant. 
I need to be able to migrate users from CouchDB to Firebase. 
Firebase offers [a super-handy-dandy auth migration tool](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users#import_users_with_md5_sha_and_pbkdf_hashed_passwords) for this. However, in order to utilize its auth migration tooling, I need to know exactly which hashing algorithm is being used for the `"simple"` `password_scheme`. 
For every user in my _users database, I have the `"salt"` and `"password_sha"` available.
Given the name `"password_sha"`, I assume that the `"simple"` `"password_scheme"` uses either `SHA1`, `SHA256`, `SHA512`, `PBKDF_SHA1`, or `PBKDF2_SHA256`.
None of the users' docs in my database have a `"derived_key"`. Almost all of them do not have a defined `"password_scheme"`. If any of them do have a defined `"password_scheme"`, it is always `"simple"` (and never `"pbkdf2"`).

Once I know exactly which hashing algorithm CouchDB uses, I then need to know how many rounds or iterations were used to hash the password. 
The Firebase docs say:

> "you must provide the number of rounds (between 1 and 8192 for `SHA1`, `SHA256` and `SHA512`, and between 0 and 120000 for `PBKDF_SHA1` and `PBKDF2_SHA256`) used to hash the password."

However, I cannot find any documentation/information on this.

So my questions are:

1. What is the hashing algorithm CouchDB uses for the "simple" "password_scheme"? (Is it SHA1, SHA256, SHA512, PBKDF_SHA1, PBKDF2_SHA256, or something else?)
2. How many rounds or iterations are used to hash the passwords?

Answer (score 0):

I posted this same question to [a few chats linked in the CouchDB homepage](https://couchdb.apache.org/#chat), and Robert Newson, owner of CouchDB, told me the following [in Slack](https://couchdb.slack.com/archives/C49LEE7NW/p1623129472338200):

> "simple" is a one round of SHA-1 (with salt)
> https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/main/src/couch/src/couch_passwords.erl#L26

So to directly answer these two questions:

1. The "simple" CouchDB hashing algorithm uses SHA1.
2. And it is only one round of hashing.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, this `simple` scheme is *not* what more recent versions of CouchDB (for sure not >= 2) use. The current default is to use `pbkdf2` with the following values:

```
iterations = 10
keylen = 20
size = 16
encoding = 'hex'
digest = 'SHA1'
```

see [couch-pwd](https://github.com/sl-nx/couch-pwd) if you need to generate or validate CouchDB-style passwords.